# Cannot find spyder after anaconda installation.

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I installed anaconda on my laptop (windows 10) and the sypder IDE was automatically installed with the Anaconda distribution. Everything seems to work fine.

However, I tried installing Anaconda on a different pc (windows 7), and I cannot find spyder. Wasn't it supposed to come with the Anaconda distribution?